# Adding selected listbox values to a multivalue field via SQL statement

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

*Edit in: The problem was that the SQL statement had to add the Areas to the MVF one at a time. The second problem was me forgetting to execute the SQL within the loop.

I have a problem in Access 2007 with some SQL statements involving a multivalue field called "area". The idea is that any one User has several relevant areas they belong to. The different areas are displayed in a multiselection listbox and inserted with the following code. After a bit of research it seemed that passing multivalue fields requires an insert. [*Though I'm unsure of this*]

My first attempt looked like this

```
For i = 0 To Me.boxArea.ListCount - 1
        If Me.boxArea.Selected(i) Then
            sqlString = sqlString & Me.boxArea.Column(boundColumnZeroBasedIndex, i) & ","
        End If
Next i
```

Which resulted in an error that states: *"The Number of values and destination fields are not the same."* The SQL string ends up as the following which made me realize it was behaving like a regular insert and the multiple values were being treated like different fields.

```
"INSERT INTO Users ([area].[Value]) VALUES(G1 ,G2,G3,) WHERE badgeNumber = '404';"
```

For my next attempt, I thought it might just require passing the values through one at a time.

```
If Me.boxArea.Selected(i) Then
            sqlString = "INSERT INTO Users ([area].[Value]) VALUES('" & Me.boxArea.Column(boundColumnZeroBasedIndex, i) & "') WHERE badgeNumber = '" + txtBadgeNumber + "';"
        End If
Next i
```

This goes through without errors, but it only includes the very last value rather than the entire string. So G3 is all that appears.

[image: Only One Value]

So now I'm confused as to how insert multiple values into a MVF through SQL within Access. Everything I've tried so far creates an error or unintended results. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

-EDITED IN INFO FOR COMMENTS

Here's a debug screen showing the value of boxArea
[image: Debug Screen]

The only other SQL Statement running is the SQL statement to create the User. I believe there's nothing wrong with it, but included as a reference.

```
sqlStr = "INSERT INTO Users ( badgeNumber, firstName, lastName, accessLevelID, department, email, phone, mobile, fax, pager, title, displayName, company )VALUES ('" + txtBadgeNumber + "', '" + txtFirstName + "', '" + txtLastName + "', 1, 'BE23515', '" + txtEmail + "', '" + txtPhone + "', '" + txtMobile + "', '" + txtFax + "', '" + txtPager + "', '" + txtTitle + "', '" + txtDisplay + "', 'XXXX');"
CurrentDb.Execute sqlStr, dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt looks like it was close.  Instead of using an update statement, use an insert.  For instance:

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO Users ([area].[Value]) VALUES ('" & Me.boxArea.Column(boundColumnZeroBasedIndex, i) & "') WHERE badgeNumber = '" + txtBadgeNumber + "';"
```

For reference, see this page on Microsoft's site:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-HA010149297.aspx

Comment: Wow didn't notice that I had an "UPDATE INTO" there. 

Corrected that, but I'm still having the same problem. Only G3, the last value passed through, is showing up in the table. Rather than values G1, G2, G3. *Added in an additional Image*

Comment: What value is being returned from "Me.boxArea.Column(boundColumnZeroBasedIndex, i)", or better yet, can you provide the multiple SQL statements that you are issuing against the database?

Comment: I just noticed that you said "G3" is the only value being stored; you'll need to insert the values one at a time, i.e. INSERT...G1, then INSERT...G2, then INSERT...G3.

Comment: That's what I believe as well. 

However, in my second attempt the loop should be inserting them one at a time. Watching the debugger, I can confirm that the SQL is inserting G1, G2, and G3 on different passes through the loop. I'm unsure why only G3 is appearing in the table.

Comment: I am new to MVF, should the ([area].[Value]) have an [i] in there somewhere? I am at a loss why it is overwriting the values rather than adding to it.

Comment: Try reading the values out of the field after each insert.  That will show you if G1 and G2 are even making it into the field.  If you would, post your code for everything inside the loop (from the FOR to the NEXT).  Perhaps we can figure this out!

Comment: I was typing a response and I think I figured it out, and I feel dumb about it. I don't think I'm executing the SQL command till after the loop. I'm off to experiment with it, but it sounds right in my head.

Comment: Yeeep. That was it. *Face Palm* Thank you for your help!